# Possible synonymous tag [splitting] and [split]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I just noticed there are two tags: [splitting](/questions/tagged/splitting) and [split](/questions/tagged/split). A quick look at a random sampling of questions tagged [splitting](/questions/tagged/splitting) suggest that these two tags could, and perhaps should, be merged (I suggest into [split](/questions/tagged/split)), as they both tend to describe the act of splitting an object.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can't we just burninate them both? I can't see what either bring to the table.

Comment: If you're talking about SO then please keep [tag:split].  It has a significant meaning in the hadoop world. That is to say, there will be questions about splits and hadoop.

Answer (score 3):

Just to be a bit more visible... Do not remove the [split](/questions/tagged/split) tag, please.  In the hadoop world the term refers to a chunk of an input to a mapper and there are many legitimate questions possible concerning the definition, distribution and processing of hadoop inputs.

The term "splitting" has no real meaning in the hadoop world.

Edit:

OK. This time I'll try to be constructive: Why not get rid of [splitting](/questions/tagged/splitting), rename [split](/questions/tagged/split) to [hadoop-split](/questions/tagged/hadoop-split) and then blacklist [split](/questions/tagged/split)?